# Convert m3u8 (HLS) to mpd (MPEG-DASH)

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, hls, mpeg-dash

I have [Live stream of HLS](https://82-80-192-30.vidnt.com/ipbc_IPBCchannel11LVMRepeat/definst/IPBCchannel11LVM_3.stream/playlist.m3u8) and I want to convert it to MPEG-DASH.

What is the best practice?

The stream is already h264 aac therefore I understand I do not need to reencode and I just need to transmux.

What should I use? ffmpeg? mp4box?

Notes:

I used [nginx-rtmp-module](https://github.com/ut0mt8/nginx-rtmp-module/) in order to create DASH from RTMP stream according to this tutorial: https://isrv.pw/html5-live-streaming-with-mpeg-dash But nginx-rtmp-module can get as input just rtmp streams and it did not work for me with HLS stream.

I used ffmpeg in order to create dash from m3u8 as following:

`ffmpeg -i https://82-80-192-30.vidnt.com/ipbc_IPBCchannel11LVMRepeat/_definst_/IPBCchannel11LVM_3.stream/playlist.m3u8 -strict -2 -min_seg_duration 2000 -window_size 5 -extra_window_size 5 -use_template 1 -use_timeline 1 -f dash out.mpd`

But this is very limited. I can't control the segment duration. The min_seg_duration parameter of ffmpeg does not work very well for me, and also it can set the minimum duration while I want to limit the maximum duration of each segment (the segment comes out with ~10 seconds, while I need it to be ~2-4 seconds as I'm playing live).